# Level system Discordjs

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am making a Level system for my bot. It's working perfectly, but there's one problem about the level system, It is when the bot making a restart, the current exp is resetting too. How can I stop it like that?

Here is my current code.

```
const db = require('quick.db');

if (!db[msg.author.id]) db[msg.author.id] = {
    xp: 0,
    level: 0
  };
db[msg.author.id].xp++;
let userInfo = db[msg.author.id];
if(userInfo.xp > 100) {
    userInfo.level++
    userInfo.xp = 0
    msg.reply("Congratulations, you level up")
}

if(msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${prefix}level`)) {
    let userInfo = db[msg.author.id];
    let member = msg.mentions.members.first();
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Level Checking')
    .setDescription("<@" + msg.member.id + ">" + ` Your current level is: ${userInfo.level}`)
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .addFields({name:"Level", value: `${userInfo.level}`})
    .addField("XP", userInfo.xp+"/100")
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Level | Reborn')
    if(!member) return msg.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
    let memberInfo = db[member.id]
    let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Level Checking')
    .setDescription("<@" + msg.member.id + ">" + ` Your current level is: ${memberInfo.level}`)
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .addFields({name:"Level", value: `${memberInfo.level}`})
    .addField("XP", memberInfo.xp+"/100")
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Level | Reborn')
    msg.channel.sendEmbed({embeds: [embed2]})
}
```

I'm using Discordjs v13

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you are connecting to a database. All I see that you are using `quick.db`
I have not used quick.db but from the way you have written I am assuming that it is storing the data in a temp variable called db. You need to store that db in a database (for you library it should be sqlite3)

Comment: Yes I added the sqlite3 at the beginning and it's perfectly working! I'm sorry for the miss codes i did

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the data in the variable `db`.
Variables always get resettet when your bot restarts.
To keep the data you need to write the data to the actual database

For example:
`db.set(msg.author.id.'level', 0)` would set the users level to 0

Check the [docs](https://quickdb.js.org/) for more inforamtion about how getting data(and how to set/modify it)

Comment: I'm having a problem about leveling, It's working perfectly fine, It's not resetting the exp when restarting the bot. The problem is, when reaching the maximum exp for level 1 It's resetting it's exp then the level still at level 1, https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/sqlite-based-points-system.md I'm using this code lines and experimenting it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use mongo db its a good database service, you can find a lot of documentation on internet and its easy to use

https://www.mongodb.com/, its free to use.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8no3SktqagY, this video will explain you everything

I hope it will help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I already transferred all my codes into mongodb. Sorry for inconvenient.

Comment: So no problem ? ya